# Normalizing a wavefunction in two dimensions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

I had a question on how to solve for $A$ in the following question.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\varphi(x,y)|^2\ dx dy = 1$$

where

$$\varphi(x,y)=A[\sin(2 \pi x)\sin(3 \pi y)+0.5\sin(3 \pi x)\sin(2 \pi y)]$$

If this can be done in Mathematica also please let me know how you did it.

Thank you!

Comment: I might be missing something but there's no decaying factor so no reason for the integral to converge.

Comment: Are you sure about those limits? These look like infinite square well wave functions so the limits should be $[0,1]$ or perhaps one of a few other choices of bounded interval. (It could also be a free particle, but this combination cannot be normalized... it integrates to infinity.)

Comment: I also did have that same question because I keep getting infinity so I was confused as to how to do this one. IF we do [0,1] what would we be getting?

Comment: If the interval is $[0,2]$ then the trigonometric functions in $\phi (x,y)$ are orthogonal to each other and so it is very easy to find A.